# No drivers for AMD Radeon HD 8750M or AMD Radeon HD 8550

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I have a pretty urgent problem. I bought Asus N56DY laptop, and all of the specs are available [here](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N56DY#specifications). The only difference is that I replaced the original HDD with an SSD. The graphic cards in question are: ATI Radeon HD 8750M (discrete graphics card) and AMD Radeon HD 8550 IGP (integrated).

My problem is that I can't find any support or drivers for the above items for Ubuntu. I use mostly Ubuntu for work, and because of this, the system acts slower. Has anybody had success in installing this type of graphic card, or has any idea when and if there will be any support for them? Is there any advice that you can give me on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have KDE(buntu) 13.04 over 3.9 kernel + Catalyst 13.8 beta driver on AMD A10 6800 APU with ATI Richland [Radeon HD 8670D]

As far as I understood from googling (I might be wrong here), Richland GPUs are not yet properly supported in the stable version 13.4. I have installed proprietary beta driver 13.8 on top of 3.9 kernel, and it worked, however OpenGL is glitchy so I use XRender. It works acceptably with occasional effects drop, which is restored by Shift-Alt-F12.

Beta driver is here 
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

You may try to set it up this way
http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/install-ati-amd-catalyst-drivers-in.html

.. or using command line, download and execute.

I would suggest trying kernel 3.8 and stable driver first, however.